# When coming out of sleep it makes me wait about 90s showing errors

Tags: 20.04, suspend

When I open my laptop lid these errors show up on screen and forces me to wait about 90s before then continuing on normally. I have an ZenBook UX481FL_UX481FL. My system information is below if that helps.

```
Linux oggyp-Laptop-ZenBook 5.4.0-54-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 10:37:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am using NVIDIA Server Driver metapackage from NVIDIA-driver-450-server

```
14:31:04 gdm3: GLib: Source ID 104 was not found when attempting to remove it
14:31:04 kernel: PM: Device 0000:04:00.0 failed to resume async: error -16
14:20:31 gdm3: GLib: Source ID 99 was not found when attempting to remove it
14:20:31 kernel: PM: Device 0000:04:00.0 failed to resume async: error -16
14:17:54 kernel: [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
14:14:27 gdm3: GLib: Source ID 94 was not found when attempting to remove it
14:14:27 kernel: PM: Device 0000:04:00.0 failed to resume async: error -16
14:06:19 kernel: [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
13:42:31 gdm3: GLib: Source ID 89 was not found when attempting to remove it
13:42:31 kernel: PM: Device 0000:04:00.0 failed to resume async: error -16
12:53:59 kernel: [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
12:38:53 gdm3: GLib: Source ID 84 was not found when attempting to remove it
12:38:53 kernel: PM: Device 0000:04:00.0 failed to resume async: error -16
12:35:16 kernel: [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
12:18:23 gdm3: GLib: Source ID 83 was not found when attempting to remove it
12:18:23 kernel: PM: Device 0000:03:00.0 failed to resume async: error -110
12:18:12 kernel: [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
12:17:37 gdm3: GLib: Source ID 77 was not found when attempting to remove it
12:17:37 kernel: PM: Device 0000:03:00.0 failed to resume async: error -110
12:12:56 kernel: [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
08:34:33 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send Intel_Write_DDC (-22)
08:34:31 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM.IDSP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
08:34:31 kernel: Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
08:34:31 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
```

Is there a fix for this or at least a way to skip the 90s I have to wait?

Comment: The 90 seconds is a default.  If I was to guess you don't have a swap.  When you close the lid the machine may be trying to hibernate and it can't do that properly.  When it wakes up it looks for nonexistent files and then after the wait it comes on.

Comment: Is there a way to make the timeout time 0 seconds?